# Can you 'checkout' from SVN without getting all the .svn stuff?

Tags: svn

Maybe there is a proper term for this, but what if you want to simply download a specific revision of a file/directory to disk and never want to commit any changes - say as part of a build/release process - and you don't want the SVN meta information.

Is there an easy command for this? Is this what export does? Or is that for dealing with "un-SVNing" an existing checkout?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're looking for **[export](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re10.html)**.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, Export should have the functionality that you're looking for -

"SVN Export to here: exports the dragged files/folders to the target location, i.e. creates a copy without the .svn folders"

From [Tortoise SVN site](http://tortoisesvn.net/most-forgotten-feature)

Answer (score 2):

[svn export is what you're searching for](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re10.html)

Answer (score 1):

Export does a copy but removes all .svn folders. So you can checkout then export.